# Is there any way to create docker-machine using Virtualbox driver with bridge network?

Tags: virtualbox, docker-machine

I want my `docker machine` use `bridge network` on `VirtualBox` but I could find any option for this on `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox` so I just fix it through `VirtualBox` settings by hand.

After fixing the network setting, However, `docker-machine ls` shows this error for the `docker machine`.

> Machine does not have a host-only adapter.

I have questions on these issues.

1. Is there any way to create `docker machine` with `bridge network` from the first.
2. In there any way to make `docker-machine` work properly after fixing the network setting to `bridge`.(for now, I am just re-creating the `docker machine` through `generic driver`)
3. If there isn't any way, why does docker prevent `bridge network`, any reason?

Comment: How did you solve it by hand?